# Getting Nearby Zip Codes from JSON Rest API in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest

I have a JSON formatted URL which is accessible here:

http://api.geosvc.com/rest/US/84606/nearby?apikey=4ff687893a7b468cb520b3c4e967c4da&d=20&pt=PostalCode&format=json

Here is the code I tried to put this JSON data into a variable:

```
var url = "http://api.geosvc.com/rest/US/84606/nearby?apikey=4ff687893a7b468cb520b3c4e967c4da&d=20&pt=PostalCode&format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

$http.jsonp(url)
    .success(function(data){
        console.debug(data);
    })
    .error(function(data){
        console.debug('error');
        console.debug(data);
    });
```

It skips the success method and goes straight to error, the error is undefined, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: console.deub(data); fix this please

Comment: that api doesn't appear to have jsonp. you are likely hitting CORS.

Comment: and not all api's serve jsonp...if not CORS enabled or jsonp enabled you have to use a proxy

Comment: How do you use a proxy? I've never heard about that.

Comment: you call your server..your server sends request for the data and prints for the ajax response. There are also third party services as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it eventually:

**zipCodes.php**

```
<?php
$url = 'http://api.geosvc.com/rest/US/84606/nearby?apikey=4ff687893a7b468cb520b3c4e967c4da&d=20&pt=PostalCode&format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
$JSON = file_get_contents($url);

// echo the JSON (you can echo this to JavaScript to use it there)
echo $JSON;
?>
```

**app.js**

```
var url = "http://samedomain.com/zipCodes.php"; 

$http.get(url)
.success(function(data){
        console.debug(data);
        $scope.zipCodes = data;
        $scope.validZipCodes = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.zipCodes, function(value, key) {
            $scope.validZipCodes.push(value.PostalCode);
        });
    })
    .error(function(data){
        console.debug('error');
        console.debug(data);
    });
```

That pulls the data super quickly